# wx dll error sometimes occurring in compiled 32bit python2.7 app

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

Python2.7, 32 bit, using wxPython2.8-win32-unicode-2.8.12.1-py27

The application fails to start on **some** Window(7 and 10) computers with the following error in the event viewer:

```
Faulting application name: CustomParts.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5b8e9a15<br>
Faulting module name: wxbase28uh_vc.dll, version: 2.8.12.1, time stamp: 0x4e2114a2<br>
Exception code: 0xc0000005<br>
Fault offset: 0x0003c623<br>
Faulting process id: 0x9c54<br>
Faulting application start time: 0x01d57ea7f9f33b4e<br>
Faulting application path: C:\projects\Signlab2019\Debug-x64\CustomParts\CustomParts.exe<br>
Faulting module path: C:\projects\SIGNLA~2\DEBUG-~1\CUSTOM~1\wxbase28uh_vc.dll<br>
Report Id: ce581fe6-0bc3-4e8b-a883-37e2156b482a<br>
Faulting package full name:<br>
Faulting package-relative application ID:<br>

SAMPLE CODE:<br>
import wx

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, 'TEST WINDOW')
frame.SetDimensions(0,0,640,480)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Used pyinstaller with a .spec file to compile the application.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you post a question, try to bring a minimum information as your problem description, input sample, output sample and what did you try. Just giving the error with no code it is very hard to help you. Try to edit your question and add some more information> Some code, where it is failing, which systems fails and which one success...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was with the wxPython module. I needed to update it to the latest version(from 2.8 to 4). This did require some code updating, due to changes in the module. I was originally thinking I couldn't update this module due to the fact I'm using an old version of Python.

Comment: Hi, I have exactly the same problem. I can understand migrating to wx v4.0 can solve the problem, but you have to migrate the whole application !!!! The problem is elsewhere and related to wx usage and setup,

Comment: the wx library has changed, but I didn't find it difficult to update my code base. Mainly deprecated methods required replacing. As for setup, I'm not sure what problem you ran into?